# Browser not detecting CSS generated by PHP?

Tags: php, caching

I'm trying to load CSS by generating it via PHP for the first time in my work.
It doesn't work for now.

So my PHP side is correct in outputting data, outputs perfectly, but maybe I'm wrong in headers or something?

```
<?php

$p = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
define('ROOT_SITE_PATH', $p);

include(ROOT_SITE_PATH . '/includes/functions.php'); # Global functions.
include(ROOT_SITE_PATH. '/includes/init.php'); # Page constants, includes for the app 'n stuff.

$init = new Init();

unset($init);

if(isset($_GET['file'])){

    $parts = explode('.', $_GET['file']);
    $ext = end($parts);

    switch(strtolower($ext)){
        case 'css':
            header('Content-Type: text/css; charset: UTF-8;'); 
            $file = DIR_STYLES . $parts[0] . '.php';
            if(is_file($file)){
                include($file);
                echo $css;
            }
        break;

        case 'js':
            header("Content-Type: text/x-javascript;");
            $file = SRC_SCRIPTS . $parts[0] . '.php';
            if(is_file($file)){
                include($file);
                echo $script;
            }
        break;
    }   
}
```

I get this output: `sitepath/dynamic_src.php?file=main.css`. Check it out.

On my server I'm testing via this main.css file, which appears not to be rendered by the browser.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sitepath/dynamic_src.php?file=main.css"/>
```

Comment: Works fine, check your <link> tag http://jsfiddle.net/zuCMp/

Comment: Your example links are broken; even when removing the whitespace. Fix them (and also the formatting) and your question might be re-opened.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I'm able to get to the example links if I remove the whitespace...

Comment: Stackoverflow won't let me change them. But I don't think they're broken after merging them?

Comment: Source view shows the main.css file on the localhost "domain" (go to view source in your browser). Change the link to the ip address and not localhost, im assuming thats your issue

Comment: Ah, you can't post links with IPs here. You should really include the relevant output in your post; possible truncated with the full output being in a proper pastebin (e.g. http://gist.github.com) - that's more reliable than a link to your dev system.

Comment: It's not path-related. If you open the link, you get CSS rules. Pls help. :(

But I have to post IPs! :/ No other way for now.

I've changed "localhost" to the IP now for you guys.

Comment: It is recognising the rules fine for me, chrome 21 on windows

Comment: Yes, for all of the other css files, but check for example body tag style. There is none. main.css is my example file (there is body tag style in main.css)

Comment: @IvanIvković It is picking up the styles, they may show as dynamic_src.php not main.css : * {
font-family: "tahoma",lucida grande,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
color: #666;
text-shadow: white 0 1px 0;
}

Comment: @IvanIvković error_reporting(0); out of topic but trust me!

Comment: There are no errors. Off topic for sure.

Comment: Turn off your error_reporting for security reason

Comment: This is my local server, not an online website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I can see clearly that your code is correct and working fine. 
Please check the page http://rajanmaharjan.com.np/test.php where you can see your style coming in my page. I have tried to include your main.css as per your design